# create a vector in R using variable names

Tags: r, vector, variable-assignment

I have a variable called school_name

I am creating a vector to define colors that I will use later in ggplot2.

```
colors <- c("School1" = "yellow", "School2" = "red", ______ = "Orange")
```

In my code I am using the variable school_name for some logic want to add that as the third element of my vector. The value changes in my for loop and cannot be hard-coded.

I have tried the following but it does not work.

```
colors <- c("School1" = "yellow", "School2" = "red", get("school_name") = "Orange")
```

Please can someone help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set the names of the colors using `names()`:

```
colors <- c("yellow", "red", "orange")
names(colors) <- c("School1", "School2", school_name)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Gordon.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `structure`:

```
school_name = "coolSchool"
colors <- structure(c("yellow", "red", "orange"), .Names = c("School1","School2", school_name))
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
school_name <- "school3"
colors <- c("School1" = "yellow", "School2" = "red")
colors[school_name] <- "Orange"
# School1  School2  school3 
# "yellow"    "red" "Orange"
```